# how to change the textcolor and image of the item clicked in the recyclerview inside navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

whatever item i am clicking it is only changing the color of the last item in the recyclerview textview and the image is also changing of the last item added
but i want that the image and textcolor of that item should change which i am clicking

this is my adapter class
           public class MyAdapter extends    RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;  // Declaring Variable to Understand which View is being worked on
                                           // IF the view under inflation and population is header or Item
     private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

      private String mNavTitles[]; // String Array to store the passed titles Value from MainActivity.java
     private int mIcons[];       // Int Array to store the passed icons       resource value from MainActivity.java
       // static TextView text; 
       // static ImageView image;
       private String name;        //String Resource for header View Name
        private int profile;        //int Resource for header view profile picture
       private String email;       //String Resource for header view email 
       static Context context;
   //static int ICONS[] =      {R.drawable.find,R.drawable.profile,R.drawable.applied,R.drawable.applied,R.drawable.resume,R.drawable.news,R.drawable.support,R.drawable.signout,R.drawable.search};
         static int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.menu_inactivefind,R.drawable.menu_inactiveprofile,R.drawable.menu_inactiveapplied,R.drawable.menu_inactiveapplied,R.drawable.menu_inactiveresume,R.drawable.menu_inactivenews,R.drawable.menu_inactivesupport,R.drawable.menu_inactivesignout,R.drawable.menu_inactivesearch};
         static int ICONS2[] = {R.drawable.findactive,R.drawable.profileactive,R.drawable.appliedactive,R.drawable.appliedactive,R.drawable.resumeactive,R.drawable.newsactive,R.drawable.support1,R.drawable.signout,R.drawable.search};


// Creating a ViewHolder which extends the RecyclerView View Holder
// ViewHolder are used to to store the inflated views in order to recycle them

    public static class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener{
    int Holderid;      

     static TextView textView; 
     static ImageView imageView;
    ImageView profile;
    TextView Name;
    TextView email;

    public ViewHolder1(View itemView,int ViewType,Context c) {                 // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
        super(itemView);
         context=c;

        // Here we set the appropriate view in accordance with the the view type as passed when the holder object is created

        if(ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText); // Creating TextView object with the id of textView from item_row.xml
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);// Creating ImageView object with the id of ImageView from item_row.xml
            Holderid = 1;
            // setting holder id as 1 as the object being populated are of type item row

          // TextView im= ((ViewHolder) itemView.getTag()).textView;
              Log.i("view",String.valueOf(textView));

         }
        else{


              Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);         // Creating Text View object from header.xml for name
              email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);       // Creating Text View object from header.xml for email
              profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleView);// Creating Image view object from header.xml for profile pic
            Holderid = 0;                                                // Setting holder id = 0 as the object being populated are of type header view
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     Toast.makeText(context,"The Item Clicked is: "+getPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


         //   imageViewz = ((ViewHolder1) v.getTag()).imageView;
         //   textViewz = ((ViewHolder1) v.getTag()).textView;
          //  imageViewz.setImageResource(ICONS2[getPosition()]);
          //  textViewz.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

            Log.i("inside",String.valueOf(textView));
    }
        }


MyAdapter(String Titles[],int Icons[],String Name,String Email, int Profile)     { // MyAdapter Constructor with titles and icons parameter
                                        // titles, icons, name, email, profile pic are passed from the main activity as we
    mNavTitles = Titles;                //have seen earlier
    mIcons = Icons;
    name = Name;
    email = Email;
    profile = Profile;                     //here we assign those passed v alues to the values we declared here
    //in adapter
     //  Log.i("myad cons",text.toString());
    }

//Below first we ovverride the method onCreateViewHolder which is called when the ViewHolder is
//Created, In this method we inflate the item_row.xml layout if the viewType is Type_ITEM or else we inflate header.xml
// if the viewType is TYPE_HEADER
// and pass it to the view holder

@Override
     public MyAdapter.ViewHolder1 onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

        ViewHolder1 vhItem = new ViewHolder1(v,viewType, context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

        return vhItem; // Returning the created object

        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder

       } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {

        View v =    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

          ViewHolder1 vhHeader = new ViewHolder1(v,viewType,context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

        return vhHeader; //returning the object created


    }
    return null;

    }

//Next we override a method which is called when the item in a row is needed to be displayed, here the int position
// Tells us item at which position is being constructed to be displayed and the holder id of the holder object tell us
// which view type is being created 1 for item row
  @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder1 holder, int position)         {
       if(holder.Holderid ==1) {                              // as the list view is  going to be called after the header view so we decrement the
                                                          // position by 1 and pass it to the holder while setting the text and image
          holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position - 1]); // Setting the Text with the array of our Titles
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position -1]);// Settimg the image with array of our icons
        //text=holder.textView;
        //image=holder.imageView;
    //  Log.i("bind",text.toString());
        }
         else{

    //    holder.profile.setImageResource(profile);           // Similarly we set the resources for header view
          holder.Name.setText(name);
          holder.email.setText(email);
      }


      }

// This method returns the number of items present in the list
       @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
       return mNavTitles.length+1; // the number of items in the list will be +1 the titles including the header view.
     }


// Witht the following method we check what type of view is being passed
    @Override
     public int getItemViewType(int position) { 
      if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;

        return TYPE_ITEM;
     }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
    }


    }
```

this is the listener in the main activity

```
              mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new      RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {


           @Override
              public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
           View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());



             if(child!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){
               //Drawer.closeDrawers();
              Toast.makeText(home.this,"The Item Clicked is: "+recyclerView.getChildPosition(child),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // ImageView imageView1 = imageView;
             //TextView textView1 = textView;

             im = ((ViewHolder1) recyclerView.getTag()).imageView;
             te = ((ViewHolder1) recyclerView.getTag()).textView;
             im.setImageResource(ICONS2[(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child))-1]);
             te.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            Log.i("text",String.valueOf(te.toString()));

               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
```

i have googled alot and searched on stackoverflow too but nothing is working .please help me i am stuck on it for few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml id to get Imageview from view, because you were not setting tag to ViewHolder

```
ImageView img = (ImageView )child.findViewById(R.id.youXmlName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the root view to your viewHolder and attaching an onclick listener to it.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public View root;

public ViewHolder ( View itemView ) {
    super ( itemView );
    this.root = itemView;

}
```

}

Set the onClickListener in onBindViewHolder like so

```
holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource("whatever image");
            holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
    });
```

edit:

Try adding the root view to your ViewHolder like so:

Comment: I have written this but no effect

Comment: i have did it like the one you have just edited else it was giving error